# Calculating distance from curve to line

Tags: geometry

Actually I am planning to sew a stuffed animal (will be an amazing corgi) and I need your help.

I am doing the sketch right now and I got a line which is $6$ cm long. Now there is another line, $8$ cm long and I want to put the ends of this longer line on the ends of the shorter line, so that there will be a curve. Now my question is, how long is the distance from the center of the curve to the shorter line?

Here is a really bad sketch from me, so that you can better understand my Problem:
[image]

How can I calculate this? Thank you very much for your advice.

**Edit:** I think the curve should be an elliptical arc.

Comment: You need to add some constraints on the shape of the curve. Is it e.g. a circular arc, an elliptical arc, a parabola, or something else? Otherwise the most that can be said is that the distance is $\le \sqrt 7$.

Comment: @Jens Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a can of worms if you want an elliptic curve, unless you mean that the curve is half of an ellipse, but it's not drawn that way. I worked out a solution for the piece of fabric as segment of a circle with chord $c$ and arc $s$. The geometry is shown in the figure below. The relevant equations are

$$
h=R-d\\
s=R\theta\\
d=R\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\\
c=2R\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\\
$$

First we need to solve for $\theta$ as follows

$$c=2R\sin\frac{\theta}{2}=s\frac{2}{\theta}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\\
\frac{2}{\theta}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{c}{s}
$$

This has to be done numerically, I found that

$$\frac{\theta}{2}\approx 1.2756981$$

We can then calculate (in this order), $R,~d$ and $h$ from the equations above. I found that $h\approx 2.2236$ for $c=6$ and $s=8$. This is consistent with the comment that suggested that $h\lt\sqrt{7}$.

[image: segment of a circle]